# Call an external command in service

Tags: delphi

I am using Shellapi's shellexecute() function to call an external command in Delphi.
When I use it in the service application, this function doesn't work. it returns 42,
winexec() also does't in the service. I know SYSTEM run the command in service. what is wrong?
anyone help me how to call an external command? thanks. simon

Comment: What user is running the Service? This makes a big difference since all the permissions will be based on the user that runs the service. Is there any error code or error message?

Comment: command I can change to "cmd" a system user can run it, right?

Comment: See [How can I call another application from my Delphi service?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14801559/576719).

Comment: Don't use `ShellExecute`. It cannot report errors properly. `ShellExecuteEx` can. That said, if `CreateProcess` can be used, it should be preferred.

Comment: Can ShellExecuteEX be used in a service?