# How to use CreateProcessWithLogonW from a service application?

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-10-seattle

I need to run a command-line application from a Windows service, executing it as another Windows user (by providing `domain\user` and `password`).

I wrapped the Windows API `CreateProcessWithLogonW()` in my own `RunAppAsAnotherWindowsUser()` function in this way:

```
function CreateProcessWithLogonW(
  lpUsername,
  lpDomain,
  lpPassword: PWideChar;
  dwLogonFlags: DWORD;
  lpApplicationName: PWideChar;
  lpCommandLine: PWideChar;
  dwCreationFlags: DWORD;
  lpEnvironment: Pointer;
  lpCurrentDirectory: PWideChar;
  lpStartupInfo: PStartupInfoW;
  lpProcessInformation: PProcessInformation
): BOOL; stdcall; external 'advapi32.dll';

function RunAppAsAnotherWindowsUser(const User, Domain, PW, Application, CmdLineParams: WideString): LongWord;    

const
  LOGON_WITH_PROFILE = $00000001;

implementation

function RunAppAsAnotherWindowsUser(const User, Domain, PW, Application, CmdLineParams: WideString): LongWord;
var
  si           : TStartupInfoW;
  pif          : TProcessInformation;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@si, sizeof(si));
  si.cb := sizeof(si);
  si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  si.wShowWindow := 1;

  SetLastError(0);
  CreateProcessWithLogonW(PWideChar(User), PWideChar(Domain), PWideChar(PW),
    LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, nil, PWideChar(Application+' '+CmdLineParams),
    CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, nil, nil, @si, @pif);
  Result := GetLastError;
end;
```

The above was [adapted from here](http://www.michael-puff.de/Programmierung/Delphi/Code-Snippets/CreateProcessWithLogonW.shtml).

When I use `RunAppAsAnotherWindowsUser ()` from a Win32 VCL application that I created for testing, it works fine.  When I call it from a Windows service, it does not work.

I read [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later/) as [advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801559/how-can-i-call-another-application-from-my-delphi-service), but in my case I do not have an interactive process, since my command-line application just does database queries and writes to a temp file.

I tried to run the service both as local system than as domain admin, but the behavior is the same.

The service is an IntraWeb (VCL for the Web) application built as a service. The same application built as exe works fine. I write this just to explain the context in which I am working in.

Could you please help me in pinpointing the issue?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having with it? Are you getting an error code? If so, which one? Please be more specific?

Comment: Services run in an isolated session, you should launch the process in the console or a user session.

Comment: I tried to run process as a user (in fact as the pc administrator), this solves a part of the problem in fact GetLastError (refer to code above) is 0 (so no 
 error), while it was 5 (to reply to @RemyLebeau) before. Anyway the exe that i run with RunAppAsAnotherWindowsUser cannot write a file, even if i put full access to everyone in the dedicated folder. Anyway it is now just a matter or permissions. Running the server as a user was an important progress, now i must fight with windows folders permissions (that are really not so obvious).

Answer (score 2):

From a service you should start the process in the user's session (on a physical pc typically the console session). This is the case since Windows Vista:

> Services have always run in session 0. Before Windows Vista, the first
>   user to log on was also assigned to session 0. Now, session 0 is
>   reserved exclusively for services and other applications not
>   associated with an interactive user session. (The first user to log on
>   is connected to session 1, the second user to log on is connected to
>   session 2, and so on.) Session 0 does not support processes that
>   interact with the user.

See [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/) for a very basic example on my blog using [Jedi Apilib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/).

From this blog:

```
uses JwaWinbase, JwaWtsApi32;       

var hToken: THandle; 
  si: _STARTUPINFOA; 
  pi: _PROCESS_INFORMATION; 
var  Ret: Cardinal; 
  sTitle: string; 
  sMsg: string; 
begin 
  ZeroMemory(@si, SizeOf(si)); 
  si.cb := SizeOf(si); 
  si.lpDesktop := nil;       

  if WTSQueryUserToken(WtsGetActiveConsoleSessionID, hToken) then 
  begin 
    if CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, nil, 'notepad.exe', nil, nil, False, 
      0, nil, nil, si, pi) then 
    begin 
      // Do some stuff 
    end; 
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: Hi, but since i need to use CreateProcessWithLogonW and not CreateProcessAsUser how can i do since CreateProcessWithLogonW  does not have token as parameter?

Comment: Get a token handle with `LogonUser` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) then change sessionid with `SetTokenInformation` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379591(v=vs.85).aspx). Pass the token to `CreateProcessAsUser`. There must be a logged on user of course, in the services session you can not launch interactive processes.

Comment: Why do you need to call CreateProcessWithLogon? Can't you impersonate the user and execute the required code in the user's context?